# Can't override bean nevertheless @Primary Spring annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, integration-testing

I have defined a bean in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` like this:

```
<!-- Datasource configuration -->
<beans:bean id="dataSource" name="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">      
   <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
   <beans:property name="url" value="" />
   <beans:property name="username" value="" />
   <beans:property name="password" value="" /> 
</beans:bean>
```

In another `config.class` (this time using Java Annotation for configuration) I would want to override this bean. This is the definition of the new bean:

```
@ImportResource(dispatcher-servlet.xml)

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public EmbeddedDatabase dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder databaseBuilder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        databaseBuilder.setName("testDB");
        databaseBuilder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2);

        return databaseBuilder.build();
    }
```

In a test I write:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = config.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
// Test
```

The unexpected result is that the bean with id dataSource that Spring chooses is the one defined in the xml file. This is the output logged:

> [info] Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a
>   different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=;
>   abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=true; factoryBeanName=Config;
>   factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in ... with [Generic bean: class
>   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]; scope=;
>   abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null;
>   factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null;
>   defined in URL [dispatcher-servlet.xml]]

It seems that `@Primary` Annotation is ignored.
 Why? What is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it is a good idea to mix different configuration types. If I were to read that kind of configuration, I would probably struggle, and believe me, I actually done quite a bit.

But, as the answer for your question, XML takes precedence over annotations. So, try to declare your bean in an XML, or use only annotations in your application.

You might try with the `@Qualifier` annotation. Maybe like this:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("my_qualifier")
public EmbeddedDatabase dataSource() {
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder databaseBuilder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    databaseBuilder.setName("testDB");
    databaseBuilder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2);

    return databaseBuilder.build();
}
```

And inject it using:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("my_qualifier")
EmbeddedDatabase database;
```

But I'm still not sure shall it work.

P.S. If you have not set up automatic annotation scanning, you should add this to you XML. From the comments you mentioned it is obsolete, but it is not.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.base.package" />
```

Just put a package containing all of your annotated classes instead of `your.base.package`, and they should be picked up by Spring, because I'm still not convinced Spring is picking them up.

Comment: I know that it is better to use only one configuration type, but I have to test a project that was configured in Xml (not by me), so now I'm forced to use Xml?

Comment: Ok, I was in a similar situation. What I had to is to make a copy of the XML configuration, throw out the parts that need to change in the tests, and set up auto scanning for the ones that we needed to mock, or implement differently. That way I did not have any conflicts, but it is a slightly tedious job.

Comment: Your solution using @Qualifier seems not working to me; what do you mean with your PS?

Comment: I meant this, covered in section 2. https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/

Comment: Yeh, this is what I have done yesterday: copy the XML configuration and throw out what I need to change, then configuring in java the new beans. But I hope that there is a better solution...

Comment: this is a very old reference, @Aleksander. For example here there is an explanation http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/122491-annotationdrivenconfig-not-found

Comment: Take a look at the P.S. again.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you mean, in the Xml there is this annotation. I thinked you were talking about @AnnotationDrivenConfig for the Java Configuration

Answer (score 2):

According to [@Primary Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) XML configuration has precedence before Java based configuration:

> If a `@Primary`-annotated class is declared via
>   XML, `@Primary` annotation metadata is ignored, and
>   `<bean primary="true|false"/>` is respected instead.

As a result bean from XML configuration will not be overridden.

Answer (score 2):

Just to use a different name (e.g. add '**2**' or '**ForTest**' suffix to it) of method in your test bean redefinition @Configuration class:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public EmbeddedDatabase dataSource2() {
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder databaseBuilder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    databaseBuilder.setName("testDB");
    databaseBuilder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2);

    return databaseBuilder.build();
}
```

or use 'name' attribute in @Bean(**name**="dataSource**2**").
That works if you @Autowired this bean by type!